# Problemas inicializacion @Value en Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot

Estoy usando spring-boot 1.5 y no se muy bien como implementar un valor pasado por la etiqueta `@Value` os pongo un ejemplo:

```
public class Clase
{
  //propiedad debidamente inicializada en su application.properties
  @Value("${propiedad.a.coger}")
  private int atributoACoger;

public int getAtributoACoger()
{
  return this.atributoACoger;
}
```

Si yo creo una nueva instancia `Clase c1 = new Clase();` el valor de `atributoACoger` es nulo.

¿Como se implementaria el @value para que coja por defecto el valor del application.properties? He probado creando constructor , pasandole el @value por parametro... pero se me agotan las ideas . ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los valores de las propiedades son *inyectados* al iniciar la aplicacion, y no en el momento que instancias una clase *manualmente*.

Te recomendaria tener una clase (como un java Bean) con los valores de configuracion, y acceder a ellos luego de que inicializas tu objecto clase.

Por ejemplo:

```
// Clase inicializada al iniciar la aplicacion
@Configuration
public class Configuracion {

  @Value("${propiedad.atributo}")
  private int atributo;

  public int getAtributo()
  {
    return this.atributo;
  }
}

...

// Clase que necesita almacenar el atributo
public class Clase {
  public Clase (int atributo){
     this.atributo = atributo;
  }

  public int getAtributo()
  {
      return this.atributo;
  }
}

...

// Algun componente que inicializa el objeto Clase, 
//   con el valor obtenido de la configuracion
@Component
public class OtraClase {
  @Inject
  private final Configuracion configuracion;

  public metodo(...){
    ...
    Clase c1 = new Clase(configuracion.getAtributo());
    ...
  }
}
```